# C++: How to use new to find store for function return value?

Tags: c++

I'm reading the 3rd edition of *The C++ Programming Language* by Bjarne Stroustrup and attempting to complete all the exercises. I'm not sure how to approach exercise 13 from section 6.6, so I thought I'd turn to Stack Overflow for some insight. Here's the description of the problem:

> Write a function *cat()* that takes two C-style string arguments and
>   returns a single string that is the concatenation of the arguments.
>   Use *new* to find store for the result.

Here's my code thus far, with question marks where I'm not sure what to do:

```
? cat(char first[], char second[])
{
    char current = '';
    int i = 0;

    while (current != '\0')
    {
        current = first[i];
        // somehow append current to whatever will eventually be returned
        i++;
    }

    current = '';
    i = 0;

    while (current != '\0')
    {
        current = second[i];
        // somehow append current to whatever will eventually be returned
        i++;
    }

    return ?
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char first[]  = "Hello, ";
    char second[] = "World!";

    ? = cat(first, second);

    return 0;
}
```

And here are my questions:

1. How do I use *new* to find store? Am I expected to do something like `std::string* result = new std::string;` or should I be using *new* to create another C-style string somehow?
2. Related to the previous question, what should I return from cat()? I assume it will need to be a pointer if I must use *new*. But a pointer to what?
3. Although the problem doesn't mention using *delete* to free memory, I know I should because I will have used *new* to allocate. Should I just delete at the end of main, right before returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I use *new* to find store? Am I expected to do something like `std::string* result = new std::string;` or should I be using *new* to create another C-style string somehow?

The latter; the method takes C-style strings and nothing in the text suggests that it should return anything else. The prototype of the function should thus be `char* cat(char const*, char const*)`. Of course this is **not** how you’d normally write functions; manual memory management is completely taboo in modern C++ because it’s so error-prone.

> Although the problem doesn't mention using delete to free memory, I know I should because I will have used new to allocate. Should I just delete at the end of main, right before returning?

In this exercise, yes. In the real world, no: like I said above, this is completely taboo. In reality you would return a `std::string` and *not* allocate memory using `new`. **If** you find yourself manually allocating memory (and assuming it’s for good reason), you’d put that memory not in a raw pointer but a smart pointer – `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

In a "real" program, yes, you would use std::string.  It sounds like this example wants you to use a C string instead.

So maybe something like this:

```
char * cat(char first[], char second[])
{
    char *result = new char[strlen(first) + strlen(second) + 1];
```

...

Q: How do you "append"?

A: Just write everything in "first" to "result".

As soon as you're done, then continue by writing everything in "second" to result (starting where you left off).  When you're done, make sure to append '\0' at the end.

Comment: Is using `strlen` anything related to programming in C++?

Comment: @Antonio: Yes, when dealing with C-style strings as stated in the question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Then not why strcpy and strcat? I think if you really want to exercise about string and memory management you should be aware of the existence of these functions, but exercise in implementing your own.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are supposed to return a C style string, so you can't use `std::string` (or at least, that's not "in the spirit of the question"). Yes, you should use `new` to make a C-style string.
2. You should return the C-style string you generated... So, the pointer to the first character of your newly created string.
3. Correct, you should delete the result at the end. I expect it may be ignored, as in this particular case, it probably doesn't matter that much - but for completeness/correctness, you should.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some old code I dug up from a project of mine a while back:

```
char* mergeChar(char* text1, char* text2){
    //Find the length of the first text
    int alen = 0;
    while(text1[alen] != '\0')
        alen++;

    //Find the length of the second text
    int blen = 0;
    while(text2[blen] != '\0')
        blen++;

    //Copy the first text
    char* newchar = new char[alen + blen + 1];
    for(int a = 0; a < alen; a++){
            newchar[a] = text1[a];
    }

    //Copy the second text
    for(int b = 0; b < blen; b++)
        newchar[alen + b] = text2[b];

    //Null terminate!
    newchar[alen + blen] = '\0';
    return newchar;
}
```

Generally, in a 'real' program, you'll be expected to use `std::string`, though. Make sure you `delete[] newchar` later!

Comment: Any particular reason for manually writing of these parts instead of using the appropriate functions (`std::strlen`, `std::strcpy`)? This is longer, less readable and more error-prone. Don’t do it.

Comment: Someone trying to learn should not be given complete sets of code that solves the exact same problem - that's not going to teach the learner anything other than CTRL-C + CTRL-V, which someone using SO probably (albeit sometimes just barely) knows.

Comment: He's asking about manipulating C-style strings. I'm showing him what's going on. If he didn't want to learn, he wouldn't have read the book in the first place. He's said he's not using the code for a real-world application, he's going over the material in the book.

Comment: And you just posted code that does exactly what his question does, so he can, potentially copy and paste either the whole thing, or portions of it, rather than writing his own code. And I'm sure you know that until you actually write code for something yourself, you don't actually know how to do that something.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I agree with you. But when you were learning a language, you must've looked up examples of what you didn't understand, no? You look them up, copy them into your editor, and play around with them until you understand how they work. He's not making a real program, he's trying to learn how memory allocation/manipulation works. I've provided something that works, and he can play around with it. This is also the reason why I didn't use the much more readable `std::strlen` etc. This is the most bare-bones version I can find that still makes sense.

Comment: My point is that you are giving all the essentials of the task he's trying to solve, in one piece. It's better to give hints and suggestions than complete pieces of code. Yes, of course I've looked up, and sometimes copied examples of code. But I did (some 25+ years ago) learn how to do all the basic string operations from scratch. At the time C++ was just a thought in Bjarne's brain (or perhaps there was some C code that had "objects") and internet was something you might find at a university, but not on home computers....

Comment: @Konrad: Why would you even use strcpy when memcpy would work since you already have the lengths thanks to strlen? Just wondering... I'd think strcpy is slower since it needs to check for the null terminator...which presumably involves code like strlen again anyway.

Comment: @Chrono I don’t see a reason why `strcpy` would be slower. You have a check in either case. Of course you could use both here but using `strcpy` is more descriptive when copying null-terminated strings, and descriptiveness trumps (almost) all other concerns. Personally, I never use `std::memcpy` – I use `std::copy` instead. It’s just as efficient and more in line with the C++ idioms of working on iterator ranges.

Comment: Fair enough. :-) +1 for `std::copy`

Answer (score 2):

What the exercise means is to use `new` in order to allocate memory. "Find store" is phrased weirdly, but in fact that's what it does. You tell it how much store you need, it finds an available block of memory that you can use, and returns its address.

It doesn't look like the exercise wants you to use std::string. It sounds like you need to return a `char*`. So the function prototype should be:

char* cat(const char first[], const char second[]);

Note the `const` specifier. It's important so that you'll be able to pass string literals as arguments.

So without giving the code out straight away, what you need to do is determine how big the resulting `char*` string should be, allocate the required amount using `new`, copy the two source strings into the newly allocated space, and return it.

Note that you normally don't do this kind of memory management manually in C++ (you use `std::string` instead), but it's still important to know about it, which is why the reason for this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use `new` to allocate memory for a string, and then return the pointer. Therefore the `return` type of `cat` would be `` `char* ``.

You could do do something like this:

```
int n = 0;
int k = 0;

//also can use strlen
while( first[n] != '\0' )
     n ++ ;
while( second[k] != '\0' )
     k ++ ;

//now, the allocation

char* joint = new char[n+k+1]; //+1 for a '\0'

//and for example memcpy for joining

memcpy(joint, first, n );
memcpy(joint+n, second, k+1); //also copying the null


return joint;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you to do this the C way pretty much:

```
#include <cstring>

char *cat (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    // Learn to explore your library a bit, and
    // you'll see that there is no need for a loop
    // to determine the lengths. Anything C string
    // related is in <cstring>.
    //
    size_t len_s1 = std::strlen(s1);
    size_t len_s2 = std::strlen(s2);
    char *dst;

    // You have the lengths.
    // Now use `new` to allocate storage for dst.


    /*
     * There's a faster way to copy C strings
     * than looping, especially when you
     * know the lengths...
     *
     * Use a reference to determine what functions
     * in <cstring> COPY values.
     * Add code before the return statement to
     * do this, and you will have your answer.
     *
     * Note: remember that C strings are zero
     * terminated!
     */

    return dst;
}
```

Don't forget to use the correct operator when you go to free the memory allocated. Otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Happy coding! :-)